# Android Studio Sceneform 2021

Tags: android-studio, sceneform

Can I know scene form is it not workable in android studio for now ?
When I install the plugin ver1.15.0 it display incompatible...
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should not be using old versions of sceneform because it does not support latest capabilities of ARcore try using https://github.com/SceneView/sceneform-android this open-source version of scenform

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this link](https://developers.google.com/sceneform/develop) by https://developers.google.com :

> Sceneform SDK for Android was open sourced and archived
> (github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk) with version 1.16.
>
> This site (developers.google.com/sceneform) serves as the
> documentation archive for the previous version, Sceneform SDK for
> Android 1.15.0.
>
> Do not use version 1.17.0 of the Sceneform Maven artifacts.
>
> The 1.17.1 Maven artifacts can be used. Other than the version,
> however, the 1.17.1 artifacts are identical to the 1.15.0 artifacts.

Comment: This means we no need to install plugin anymore ? Because when I click Install it will shows the incompatible messages.

Comment: As I know, yes. you can not install it any more